# PIC uc programming whitout MCLR pin

Tags: microcontroller, hardware, pic

I am using PIC18F26K22 chip. The MCLR pin of my chip is damaged and don't work(When I tie this to Vss, the chip don't get reset and I am not able to program my chip). Is there any way that I can program my chip without this pin?

Note : The programmer is PICKIT3.

Comment: what did the chip documentation say were your programming choices?

Comment: @old_timer what do yo means?Always I use PICKIT programmer,also i program this  chip before.

Comment: The pickit3 is just a tool, the chip is the chip.  The chip documentation shows what signals are required for programming the device, if there are any alternate solutions like a built in bootloader (unlikely for that device/brand).  the pickit3 simply supports that or one of those protocols, there may be an alternate.  But the answer to your question is in that documentation, we are not here to read that document for you, you need to do that first.

Comment: There are a lot of documents for chip and programmer.I know must read those document to answer my question.All of questions in stackoverflow are answered in reference documents and other reference site.I am and the others asking questions here because of the prompt reply.

Comment: with respect to this question based on the PIC parts I have read about there should only be one document you have to read a small section on or perhaps two.  The time it has taken for you to write the question and comments and wait you could have read those few paragraphs hundreds of times over and over again...Looks like someone has read the paragraphs for you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pin may not actually be damaged.  There is a configuration fuse that disables the reset functionality (page 348 of the data sheet). The high voltage programming entry will still operate when the MCLR function is disabled.

If the pin is truly damaged you may see if LVP (low voltage programming) is enabled.  For some additional information on LVP you might look here : https://www.microforum.cc/topic/15-programming-a-picmicro-without-high-voltage/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely no. You can get away with damaged MCLR in LVP (low voltage programming) mode, but the default is the other one (high-voltage). Any attempts to circumvent this would cost more than the new component. See this for more details -> http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41398B.pdf

Answer (score 0):

without MCLR it is not possible